# Python 3.4: contour plot display on dynamic map using unstack and mplleaflet

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, geopandas

I am having a problem getting a contour plot to display on top of an mplleaflet map. I am fairly certain this is because I'm not sure how to tell mplleaflet where to orient my contour plot on the map. So, the question is about how to do this.

Below I have constructed the following simple example based on the code found here:
https://github.com/jwass/mplleaflet/blob/master/examples/contour.py.

While the author of that example has determined his coordinate reference system, I have been unable to do so. Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplleaflet
import pandas as pd

# Fictional lon/lat data in pandas data frame:
df= {'Lat': pd.Series([40.0,40.0,40.0,41.0,41.0,41.0,42.0,42.0,42.0]),
     'Lon': pd.Series([-69.0,-70.0,-71.0,-69.0,-70.0,-71.0,-69.0,-70.0,-71.0]),
     'Val': pd.Series([0,1,2,0,1,0,2,2,1])}
 df=pd.DataFrame(df)

#Change indices, unstack, and sort:
df.set_index(['Lat','Lon'],inplace=True)
df=df.unstack()
df.sort_index(axis=0,inplace=True)
df.sort_index(axis=1,inplace=True)

#Extract data, make a contour plot
g=df['Val']
plt.contour(g.columns.values,g.index.values,g)

#Define the crs - completely wrong I know, but what to do?
crs= {'lon_0': -105.0,
      'lat_ts': 60.0,
      'R': 6371200,
      'proj': 'stere',
      'units': 'm',
      'lat_0': 90.0}
```

Now, not surprisingly, when I do the command:

```
mplleaflet.show(crs=crs)
```

A blank map of the world pops up - my contour plot nowhere to be found. Of course, this is very likely because my `crs` is defined incorrectly. Does anyone know how to go about doing this, or even figuring out how to set the parameters in python. I might also add that there is virtually no Python documentation on how to do this.

Best,

Matt

p.s. I'm running Python 3.4 in Windows 7, and I was also unable to get the example at https://github.com/jwass/mplleaflet/blob/master/examples/contour.py working.

Answer (score 0):

Use geopandas to create the correct projection:

```
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point

s = geopandas.GeoSeries([Point(4.42, 50.4), Point(4.43, 50.2)])

s.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326', 'no_defs': True}

s.to_crs(epsg=31370)
```

Result:

```
0     POINT (153643.9201303074 121012.188949639)
1    POINT (154373.4245113489 98766.94731544051)
dtype: object
```